Let $f(x)$ be a differentiable function and suppose $\lim_{x\to\infty}{f(x+3)-f(x)} = 2013$. Calculate $\lim_{x \to\infty} \frac{f(x)}{x}$.
Let $f(x)$ be a differentiable function and suppose $\lim_{x\to\infty}{\left(f(x+3)-f(x)\right)} = 2013$. Calculate $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}.$
My attempt:
The equation $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x+3)-f(x)=2013$ suggests that the function grows linearly while $x\to \infty$,
$f(x+3) - f(x) \approx f'(x) \cdot 3 = 2013 \implies f'(x) = \frac{2013}{3} = 671$.
So, $f(x) = 671x + C$. 
$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{x} = 671$
I'm not sure that it's correct. Can you help me with modifying my solution?

Welcome to MSE! Please note that it's not the best idea to put the whole problem in the title.

To me it is obvious to spot that $f(x) = 671x + C$ is a family of solutions. But for the answer to be $671,$ we also need to show that if $\frac{f(x)}{x}\not\to 671,$ then $\lim_{x\to\infty}{\left(f(x+3)-f(x)\right)} \not\to 2013.$ Although this should not be too difficult.

If you trust the problem setter, the answer to the limit must be the same for all functions that meet the requirement.  @AdamRubinson has given you a family of functions that do with the common limit $671$, so if there is a consistent answer that is it.
